# PostgreSQL - Why is this Index only scan slower than the Index scan?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

We have a table `foo_tbl` (name obsfucated, same data type and DDL):

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.foo_tbl (
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    foo_id varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    foo_date timestamptz NULL,
    -- ... other unrelated columns ...

    CONSTRAINT pk_footbl PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX idx_1_2cols ON public.foo_tbl USING btree (foo_date, foo_id); -- initial index
CREATE INDEX idx_2_1col ON public.foo_tbl USING btree (foo_id); -- added later, when the query is slow
```

We have a big query that join 7 tables with this table using `foo_id` and getting `foo_date` out.
Example (real query is much bigger):

```sql
select b.bar_code, f.foo_date from bar_tbl b join foo_tbl f on b.bar_id = f.foo_id limit 100;
```

Without the join with `foo_tbl` the query is fast (< 2s).

After add the join with `foo_tbl`, the query is much slower (> 15s), despite running an "Index Only Scan" on `foo_tbl` using index `idx_1_2cols` (only these 2 columns of this table are used in the query). This is the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` result for the table:

```json
{
  "Node Type": "Index Only Scan",
  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
  "Parallel Aware": false,
  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
  "Index Name": "idx_1_2cols",
  "Relation Name": "foo_tbl",
  "Schema": "public",
  "Alias": "f",
  "Startup Cost": 0.42,
  "Total Cost": 2886.11,
  "Plan Rows": 1,
  "Plan Width": 20,
  "Actual Startup Time": 12.843,
  "Actual Total Time": 13.068,
  "Actual Rows": 1,
  "Actual Loops": 1200,
  "Output": ["f.foo_date", "f.foo_id"],
  "Index Cond": "(f.foo_id = (b.bar_id)::text)",
  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
  "Heap Fetches": 0,
  "Shared Hit Blocks": 2284772,
  "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
  "I/O Read Time": 0.0,
  "I/O Write Time": 0.0
}
```

To investigate, we created the single column index `idx_2_1col` and the query is fast again (< 3s). When EXPLAIN, the planner choose the new index over the old index for an "Index scan":

```json
{
  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
  "Parallel Aware": false,
  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
  "Index Name": "idx_2_1col",
  "Relation Name": "foo_tbl",
  "Schema": "public",
  "Alias": "f",
  "Startup Cost": 0.42,
  "Total Cost": 0.46,
  "Plan Rows": 1,
  "Plan Width": 20,
  "Actual Startup Time": 0.007,
  "Actual Total Time": 0.007,
  "Actual Rows": 1,
  "Actual Loops": 1200,
  "Output": ["f.foo_date", "f.foo_id"],
  "Index Cond": "((f.foo_id)::text = (b.bar_id)::text)",
  "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
  "Shared Hit Blocks": 4800,
  "Shared Read Blocks": 0,
  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
  "I/O Read Time": 0.0,
  "I/O Write Time": 0.0
}
```

So, why is the Index scan in this case faster than the Index only scan? And why is the Index only scan so slow?

Notes:

- Already `VACUUM ANALYZE` before `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the query
- The `foo_tbl` is not the biggest, just some hundred thousands records, some tables in the join contains millions of records.
- DBS is Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible 13.5 (not serverless)

Comment: The JSON format of EXPLAIN plans is good for machines to read.  But you are asking humans, not machines.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's easier to read on small screens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-most column in a multi column index is the one that should be queried. In your case, the `foo_date` is only returned and the value check is done solely on the second column `foo_id`.

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) is clear about this and even state that in such situation the entire index is to be scanned and the planner is likely to scan the entire table instead.

> A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that
> involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most
> efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost)
> columns. The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading
> columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does
> not have an equality constraint, will be used to limit the portion of
> the index that is scanned. Constraints on columns to the right of
> these columns are checked in the index, so they save visits to the
> table proper, but they do not reduce the portion of the index that has
> to be scanned.

You can try switching the columns in the index, or to create a [covering index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) by including the date in the 2nd index to avoid touching the table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the DDL for `bar_tbl` hasn't been provided, the following is just an educated guess.

The query planner apparently chose to use `idx_1_2cols` because it has both columns that are needed and the planner estimated that using the index would be more efficient than scanning the base table (it most definitely should be since reading the table would require many more block reads due to the unneeded columns).

The problem is that the join is on `foo_id`, but the index prefix is `foo_date`. Change the index order to (`foo_id, foo_date`) and the query will run much more quickly.

Adding `idx_2_1col` improved performance because the join between `bar_id` and `foo_id` could be made efficiently using the index, even though reads from the base table were also needed to satisfy the query.

Answer (score 0):

From the slow query plan:

"Index Cond": "(f.foo_id = (b.bar_id)::text)",

The cast on one side but not the other suggests the planner isn't sure the types match exactly. Is there some discrepancy between the ID columns of the 2 tables, like one is a string and one is an integer, or they're strings of different length, character set, etc.?

In the subsequent example where the query speeds up again, there's

"Index Cond": "((f.foo_id)::text = (b.bar_id)::text)",

which at least is treating both sides equally w.r.t. type coercion.